# JAXB unmarshalling with java generics

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshall an XML document from a legacy system using JAXB. I have an xml structure as follows :

```xml
<response>
    <id>000000</id>
    <results>
        <result>
<!-- Request specific xml content -->
            <year>2003</year>
            <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
            <items>
                <item>I1</item>
                <item>I2</item>
            </items>
        </result>
        <result>
            <year>2007</year>
            <title>Dolor sit amet</title>
            <items>
                <item>K1</item>
                <item>K2</item>
            </items>
        </result>
    </results>
</response>
```

The tags inside the part specified by `<result>` tag will change depending on my request.  Since the content may change I decided to use generics for result items and I have prepared my java beans with annotations as following:

```java
// imports here
@XmlRootElement(name="response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XResponse<T>{
    private String id;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="results")
    @XmlElement(name="result")
    private List<T> results;

// setters and getters
}

...

@XmlRootElement(name="result")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class X1Result{
    private String year;
    private String title;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="items")
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private List<String> items;

// setters and getters
}
...
```

I tried unmarshalling the xml document via the code below:

```java
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XResponse.class, X1Result.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
XResponse<X1Result> response = (XResponse<X1Result>) um.unmarshal( xmlContent );

List<X1Result> results = unmarshal.getResults();
for (X1Result object : results) {
    System.out.println(object.getClass());
}
```

I have a problem during the unmarshalling that it can't cast the list items into `X1Result` class. Instead it uses `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl`.

What should I do to make JAXB Unmarshaller use `X1Result` class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use inheritance instead of generics.  Given an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id>000000</id>
    <results>
        <result xsi:type="X1Result">
            <year>2003</year>
            <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
            <items>
                <item>I1</item>
                <item>I2</item>
            </items>
        </result>
        <result xsi:type="X1Result">
            <year>2007</year>
            <title>Dolor sit amet</title>
            <items>
                <item>K1</item>
                <item>K2</item>
            </items>
        </result>
    </results>
</response>
```

You can dynamically bind your `<result>` entries.  You have a top-level type:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "XResult")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    X1Result.class
})public abstract class XResult {

}
```

And you have implementing classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "X1Result")
public class X1Result extends XResult {
    @XmlElement(name = "year")
    private String year;

    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    private List<String> items;
    ...
}
```

Use the top-level type in your XResponse class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "results")
    @XmlElement(name = "result")
    private List<XResult> results;
    ...
}
```

And you can unmarshall using the top-level type:

```
context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XResponse.class, XResult.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
XResponse response = (XResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("testfile.xml"));

List<XResult> results = response.getResults();
for (XResult object : results) {
    System.out.println(object.getClass());
}
```

Comment: The code above initializes `XResult` instead of `X1Result` and therefore it gives error since it is an abstract class. Besides the content of the xml is coming from a legacy system and there is no `xsi:type` information available. (although I may add it programmatically)

Comment: The code will instantiate an `X1Result` if the `xsi:type` is there.  At least, that's what it does for me.  Good luck.

Comment: This worked fine for me without the `xsi:type` present in the XML.  I'm using Java 1.7.0_15.